# g++ alignment problem

Tags: c++, gcc, alignment

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = 0;
    printf("%lX\n", &x);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this code using mingw32-c++.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
prints `0x22FF24` which is `0b1000101111111100100100`. 
Compiling and running this code using g++ (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2 prints `0x7FFFF470EE90` which is `0b11111111111111111110100011100001110111010010000`.

Due to the alignment I expect the last 7 bits of the variable's address to be zero. Do I make an error in reasoning here? What's going on?

Thanks in advance,

Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16=2<sup>4</sup>, so I would expect the last 4 bits of the address to be zero if the address was aligned to a 16-byte boundary.

The stack is generally not guaranteed to have any sort of alignment on x86, see [Bug 16660](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16660).  Also, GCC is dependent on the linker for alignment of global/common variables, and binutils prior to 2.20 were not really capable of doing so on Windows.

Comment: You are right, I misinterpreted the parameters meaning. For alignment to 7 bits I should specify `__attribute__ ((aligned (128)))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer to question [GCC `__attribute__((aligned(x))` explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841433/gcc-attributealignedx-explanation) which says:

> Because the stack pointer could be
>   anything when the function starts,
>   there is no way to align the array
>   without allocating a lot more than you
>   need and adjusting it