# How to align stack variable to 16byte boundary

Tags: c, alignment, callstack

I have the following local variable (that will get stored in the stack).

```
struct test1 {
  int a;
  int b;
  char c;
};
```

How do I align the starting address of integer `a` to a `16byte` boundary in the stack?

I am running this C code on a custom written MIPS ISA processor.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841433/gcc-attribute-alignedx-explanation

Answer (score 2):

Here is some non-standard way of aligning your data.

```
struct test1 *pdata;

// here we assume data on stack is word aligned
pdata = alloca(sizeof(*pdata) + 14);
if (pdata & 0xF)
{
    pdata = (unsigned char*)pdata + 16 - (pdata & 0xF);
}
```

Comment: should be alloca(sizeof(*pdata) + 15); no?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK On MIPS ISA C compilers are forced align to word boundaries in this case, just add an int (which is 32 bit)  to the structure. so:

```
struct test1 {
   int a;       // 4 bytes
   int b;       // 4 bytes
   int foralign;// 4 bytes for 16 byte alignment
   char c;      // 1 byte but will be aligned 4 bytes

};
```

Comment: Tecnhincally it just grows in size, but doesn't become 16-byte aligned.

Comment: @Valeri  It will grow into 16 bytes if compiler word alignment is switched on... yep. If I am wrong inform me so I will erase my answer. I do not like unnecessary answer piles in SO too... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no *standard* way to get objects aligned like that.  There's almost always some compiler-specific trick, such as `__attribute__` in GCC, but you'll have to check your compiler's documentation.

(Of course there's no standard *use* for that kind of alignment either, which is why there's no standard method for achieving it.  So you're probably resorting to extensions already, so there's no real harm going further.)

A union that contains a large-enough elemental object often does the trick, but I believe the largest elemental C objects for MIPS CPUs are `long long` and `double`, which are only 8 bytes.