# How to guarantee aligned field in a packed class?

Tags: c++, gcc

I thought the "aligned" attribute will always be respected. But I tried the code sample below, and the output was "16 19". I was expecting "16 24". I used g++. Why the compiler ignored the "aligned" attribute in this case? Does "packed" take precedence over "aligned"? Is there a way to make sure Test1 is always properly aligned to 8?

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

class Test1
{
public:
   uint8 t1;
   uint64 t2;
}  __attribute__ ((aligned(8)));

class Test2
{
private:
   uint8 t1;
   uint8 t2;
   uint8 t3;
   Test1 t4;
} __attribute__ ((packed));


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   Test1 t1;
   Test2 t2;    
   printf("%ld %ld\n", sizeof(t1), sizeof(t2));
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make sure Test1 is always properly aligned to 8? you can always `assert(((int)&t1) % 8 == 0)`. Will break at runtime.

Comment: yes, but I need a solution that doesn't break at run-time.

Comment: Might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841433/gcc-attribute-alignedx-explanation

Comment: This is GCC, I assume?

Comment: It is ignoring the alignment requirement for Test1.  Seems reasonable when you say "ignore alignment and pack tightly", a struct isn't treated differently from an uint64.  Fix it by inserting a dummy field that takes enough space.  Or omit the attribute completely, also gives you what you want.

Comment: Yes, this is GCC (g++ to be more exact).

Comment: Let's assume that I have directly control of Test1. But Test2 is shared by many developers and thus things like manual padding may not be ideal. To me "aligned" is a correctness issue. If read of Test1->t2 takes multiple instructions, it will cause atomic issues. On the other hand, "packed" is a performance optimization that may save some memory space. So I am surprised that GCC respect "packed" more than "aligned".